# Is there a way I can get the inventory amount in every month and calculate their age SQL?

Tags: sql, powerbi, oracle-sqldeveloper

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhdZw.png)

As what you see in the image above. I have this buckets, basically it is the age of an item. the computation of it is something like Date now - Receiving_date of the item. I already have the logic on this one however it is made in oracle BI where there is a criteria. I need to apply the same logic or if there's a way in my dataset and import it to powerBI. Basically, there's a multiple age until above 365 days. I need to get the snapshot of ending inventory per item. So basically all months have its own <30 days of aging and also my inventory amount is in another table. Help will be highly appreaciated. Thank you!

I am expecting to get the same result in the image that I post.

Comment: You need to provide sample input data (as text not images) and desired sample output, clearly explaining how to get from one to the other.  You need to explain if you are looking for a solution in Oracle, SQL, M or DAX. If DAX, you need to additionally provide the structure of the table and relationships you have set up. Without all of this, no one can help you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)